# formation of a compound due to photo-isomerisation

Tags: organic-chemistry, photochemistry

I was reading through a topic called photoisomerism, where I read that when a molecule is hit by a photon it changes its structure to a more stable one. Is this a one-way reaction, or is it reversible (as in is it an equilibrium)? **If** it was an equilibrium, what was stopping it from forming before the photon hit it?

update

since the question was a bit ambiguous, my question was after the light that was shone was removed, if the equilibrium still exists, then what was the hindrance that did not allow such equilibrium to exist before the light was shone. (i am not sure if such a reaction exists, my question is more of a hypothetical question, asking if such a reaction exists then what was hindrance from reaching equilibrium (that was achieved after the shone light was removed)  before the light was shone)(if no such reaction can exist please also explain why so)

Comment: What molecule? And you have heard about *activation energy*?

Comment: I'm surprised to see this question getting downvoted, as it has merit.  It is a deceptively difficult question, and probably too broad to be answered briefly.  I would like to see someone try to answer it, myself.

Comment: @Karl might be retinol, although OP would have to confirm.

Comment: @Bertram The question is (still) very sloppily and unclearly written. It could easily be improved, and then one could give a good answer.

Comment: @Karl I do know the concept of activation energy. hence I have asked in a condition of equilibrium and not a one-directional reaction. it is very evident that in a single direction reaction it is nothing but a photochemical reaction. I am asking in an equilibrium reaction (if it is possible)(with k less than 100 and greater than 0.1) what was the hindrance of the photoisomer not forming before light was shone on the molecule. and sorry this was the first time I am asking on stack exchange so the ambiguity in the answer

Comment: If the structure the molecules changes into is more stable, then the equillibrium must be very much on *that* side. And if a reaction does not reach its equillibrium, the hindrance always includes some activation energy. I'm sure you know that, so what is your question?

Comment: I'm asking if on shining the light **if** it reaches an equilibrium. what was not allowing it before shining this light from reaching this equilibrium. the point of equilibrium is that it should still be in equilibrium even after the light that is shone is removed. (I'm not sure if such reaction exists that a new equilibrium is formed after light which is shone is removed, I'm asking if such a reaction exists why was the equilibrium not reached after the light was shone)

Comment: (You need to work on your grammar and syntax a bit, it's very hard to follow.) Generally there is one equillibrium with the light on, and another one with the light off, AND it could be that the reaction reaches the equillibrium, or not. How different those two equillibria are also strongly depends on the wavelength and intensity. Not sure if I understand your question correctly, but I think there is no general answer.

Comment: ‘Is this a one-way reaction, or is it reversible (as in is it an equilibrium)?’ – this can only be answered for the specific, individual reaction. Hence why *needs detail.*

Answer (score 5):

Stilbene has been extensively studied with pump-probe absorption spectroscopy as well as time resolved fluorescence.

[image: stilbene]

In the ground state (S0) there is a large activation energy to go from trans  to cis and vice versa so that both species are stable at room temperature. This is not the case in the first excited state (S1)and the trans converts to the cis in a few tens of picoseconds and it is even faster for the cis excited state to convert to the trans.

The potential energy scheme is shown below (Not to scale). On the left is the trans species with a large barrier to for the cis (on the right). This has a higher energy than the trans but also has a large barrier to form the trans.

Detailed analysis suggest that the reaction occurs by a lengthening of the double bond before twisting. Exciting the trans puts it into the first singlet excited state (S1) where there is a small barrier on the pathway to cis, but as it happens there is an intersection with the ground state (by 3ps label & twisted species) and from here either the ground state trans or ground state cis can be formed. If the cis ground state is excited then there is effectively no barrier to form the trans ground state and the excited cis molecule lasts for only a few ps.

[image: stilbene-PES]

For a review or organic photochemistry calculations see Bernardi et al. Chemical Society Reviews, p321, 1996, in particular fig 1. A lot of the original experimental work was done by the Hochstrasser group, see Annu. Rev. Phys. Chem. 2006. 57:37–64 for many references.